# Title and icon not being displayed in ionic tab app

Tags: ionic-framework

not sure why i am having such a hard time making tabs work in the ionic app..

Here is the html:

```
<body>

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive"> </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" ui-sref="home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>

</body>
```

Here is the routing:

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      home: {
        template: 'home.html',
      }
    }
  });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

});
```

When I run this simple app, I expect the tab to display a title and icon.. but that's not happening..

There seems to be no explicit error messages which makes things worse.

http://plnkr.co/edit/K1nAtL

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">
```

With

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">
```

then add  the ionic font it will work.